# Is this homebrewed divine version of Abjurant Champion balanced? (Stalwart Protector version 2)

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, homebrew-review, divine

Here is my second stab at a divine Abjurant Champion I have reevaluated some of the requirements and tied the class to Conjuration instead of abjuration

The general flavor of the class is meant to be a divine templar-esque kind of fighter, a protector of the weak or shield of the innocent type. It is intended to be a prestige class for Fighter with a dip of Cleric or Paladin, combining all the martial prowess of a fighter with a clerics or paladin's religious pious nature. Basically a cleric/paladin without the alignment straitjacket.

Is this homebrewed prestige class better balanced now?

---

> ## Stalwart Protector
>
> The divine champion focuses his divine abilities both to augment his personal defense and to hinder enemy spellcasters. Perfectly suited for martial stalwarts who dabble in magic, this class offers characters the ability to improve their combat skills in ways neither soldiers nor spellcasters can.
>
> Requirements
>
> **Alignment:** Any non-evil
>
> **Spellcasting:** Must be able to cast 1st-level divine spells, at least one of which is Conjuration(healing).
>
> **Special:** Must be proficient with at least one martial weapon.
>
> ### Class Features
>
> **Base Attack Bonus:** Full progression to +5 over 5 levels
>
> **Base Saves**: Good Will, Poor Reflex and Poor Fortitude
>
> **Hit die**: d10
>
> **Skill points:** 2 + Int
>
> **Spellcasting:** At each level, you gain new spells per day and an increase in caster level (and spells known, if applicable) as if you had also gained a level in a divine spellcasting class to which you belonged before adding the prestige class level. You do not, however, gain any other benefit a character of that class would have gained. If you had more than one divine spellcasting class before becoming an stalwart protector, you must decide to which class to add each level for the purpose of determining spells per day, caster level, and spells known.
>
> **Divine Grace (Su):** Stalwart Protectors are a boon to the downtrodden and heal others more effectively than themselves. Any time you cast a conjuration spell that heals hp of another player you can increase the amount healed by your stalwart protector class level.
>
> **Swift Cure (Su):** Beginning at 2nd level, you can cast *Cure* spells as a swift action, as if you had applied the Quicken Spell feat to them (but without any change in level). The maximum level of spell you can quicken in this way is equal to your class level.
>
> **Augmented Summons (Su):** Beginning at 3rd level, any creatures summoned by you have the *celestial* template applied to them.
>
> **Divine Boost (Su):** Beginning at 4th level, you gain the ability to burn Turn/rebuke uses to empower your martial abilities. As a swift action, you can spend one or more of your Turn/ Rebuke uses to grant yourself one of the following insight bonuses for 1 round.
>
> - Bonus on attack rolls equal to the number of uses spent.
> - Bonus on weapon damage rolls equal to twice the number of uses spent.
> - Bonus to AC equal to the number of uses spent.
> - Bonus on saving throws equal to the number of uses spent.
> - Resistance to acid, cold, electricity, fire, and sonic equal to 5 × the number of uses spent.
>
> **Divine Fury (Ex):** At 5th level, you master the art of combining your militant and divine training. From this point on, your caster level in a chosen Divine spellcasting class is equal to your base attack bonus (unless it would otherwise be higher). For example, a 7th-level fighter/1st-level cleric/5th-level stalwart protector has a base attack bonus of +12 (and thus a caster level of 12th). You can apply this benefit to only one divine class to which you have added spellcasting levels by your advancement as an stalwart protector.
>
> ---

**Errata:** Remove requirement "at least one of which is Conjuration(Healing)" replace with "and must have *access* to the Healing Domain"

Comment: You are correct, I was using a spell list that curiously divides Cleric spells in to spell schools, something that the PHB does not.

Comment: Wait, is the errata applied in the write-up or not? What is the final, intended requirement? Also, you highlight “access”—does that mean that they must have had healing domain as an option, or that they must have actually selected it? That phrasing is how WotC requires having a domain but the emphasis makes me wonder if that’s the intent here.

Comment: @KRyan The final intended requirement is the one reflected in the errata. I didn’t change the write up to preserve the validity of your comment. And yes the intention in the wording is that they have the healing domain as one of there domain options, but not necessarily one of the ones they chose. I.E. a cleric of Pelor whose two chosen domains are Good and Strength. What would be a better wording for this? “Must have the healing domain available as an option”?

Comment: I’m going to address that in my answer then, I think. But you could have just edited that, seeing as no one had even answered the question before you put in the errata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Better than the first, but augmented summons is a dud

Almost all Conjuration (Healing) spells, including all *cure* spells, are really weak, but a free Quicken goes a long way to improving them. They should still probably be reserved for emergencies—most other spells it the same level are likely better uses of the spell slot—but being able to spontaneously heal someone in an emergency *without* seriously interrupting your own turn is very good.

On the other hand, +5 healing doesn't do much but then neither did abjurant champion’s +5 armor bonus to AC. So that’s probably fine. But while we’re on the subject, “divine grace” is already the name of a powerful, well-known class feature, the paladin’s ability to add Cha to all saves. So you should probably use a different name.

Augmented summons is weird. One, a martial/healer character will probably never bother to summon anything—the 1-round casting time is just prohibitive and what you get is a bit middling. Second, again, that name is already in use, by a feat which does something else entirely. Thirdly, a cleric’s only summoning spells are the *summon monster* line—which already adds the celestial template to a large portion of the options. Those it doesn’t add the celestial template to, are already celestial, or else are elemental or fiendish—which don’t really make a lot of sense gaining the celestial template. Finally, celestial is a really weak template—it’s useful for making your summon intelligent so you can order it verbally rather than needing Handle Animal, but that benefit doesn’t apply to anything in the *summon monster* list. Those are all already intelligent.

Finally, it was mentioned in comments in the last case that divine boost is potentially susceptible to abuse in cases where a character has a very-high number of turn/rebuke undead uses. For the most part, I tend to think those abuses require more effort than they’re worth here, and if any of them are really too powerful, you should probably be looking at the source of turn/rebuke uses rather than this feature, but if you wanted to be conservative about things, you could put a limit of 9 uses at a time on it, to match abjurant champion (or 10 just for a round number, or whatever number is comfortable).

#### Also, about that requirement

“Must have domains and worship a deity or faith that offers the healing domain,” is, I believe, the best way to word that. I might even throw in “though you need not have chosen the healing domain,” just to be really explicit. It’s a pretty weird requirement, though, especially so with a cleric of ideals (can I say my ideal could include healing, but I’ve chosen something else?). All-in-all though, it’s better than requiring healing, because where protection is mediocre, healing is terrible (the granted ability is tiny, the spells on the list are all cleric spells anyway, and seven out of nine are awful, the exceptions being the proper *heals*).

Ultimately, I’m not really a fan of the domain requirement. Part of the reason abjurant champion was so nice is that it was so flexible—it could be useful to a whole lot of different characters. That’s appropriate, particularly for a 5-level class.

#### An alternative thought

Has this player looked at the crusader from *Tome of Battle*? It seems like a more streamlined, balanced version of what you seem to be trying to enable with this prestige class. It’s also one of my most highly recommended classes in the game. And some spells are desired, the ruby knight vindicator prestige class from the same melds cleric and crusader very well.

Comment: It's also noteworthy that a cleric taking this class loses their good Fort save progression. It's not a significant blow, but it's...odd, for a class designed to make the cleric a better melee combatant.

Comment: I appreciate the time you've taken to look into this, I will take your suggestions into account and present them to my player. If he wants to continue with the prestige class I might publish an updated version in a new question.